# Passing a string or a variable from a dialoguebox to an activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I wan to implicitly pass two string or variable from a dialoguebox  to be used by another activity and at the same time opening that activity.

dialoguebox

```
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String category = "Hazard";

            AlertDialog.Builder prompt = new  
             AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
            prompt.setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Mineralization", new 
             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    .setPositivetiveButton("Geohazard", new 
                           DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                                int which) {

                                    startActivity(new  
                        Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class));

                        //i want to pass the String city and category here
                                }
                            }
                    )





            AlertDialog alert = prompt.create();
            alert.setTitle("Please select an option");
            alert.show();

            TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PSString);
            myTextView.setText(city);
```

New activity

```
package com.example.boneyflesh.homepage;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GeohazardResults extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geohazard_results);
    }
}
```

how do i do this? what do i write on the onClickListener and what do i do on the new activity so that i can get the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing something like this in your onClick method

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class));
```

You can just pass the two strings through the intent to the `MapsActivity` inside your onClick method as shown below

```
Intent lIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
lIntent.putExtra("city", city);
lIntent.putExtra("category", category);
startActivity(lIntent);
```

and retrieve those values in `MapsActivity` as shown below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_geohazard_results);
    String city = getIntent().getStringExtra("city");
    String category = getIntent().getStringExtra("category");
}
```

Comment: great,,thanks man. the other answers work as well but i chose this one for being explicit and simple to understand for beginners like me. :thumbs-up:

Comment: @Boneyflesh You should consider upvoting the useful answers (in addition to selecting the "winner")

Comment: @theblitz i did upvote them but it says that the public status will change once my reputation is more than 15 T_T.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this -:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class));
```

Do something like this -:

```
Intent mapsActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);
mapsActivityIntent.putExtra("CITY", city);
mapsActivityIntent.putExtra("CATEGORY", category);
startActivity(mapsActivityIntent);
```

In your activity you can then get them by doing :

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("CITY");
getIntent().getStringExtra("CATEGORY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Using Intent and Bundle like Below:

```
Intent intent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class));
Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key1","value1");
bundle.putString("key2","value2");
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent );
```

And Retrieve value in next Activity like below:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String value1= bundle.getString("key1");
String value2= bundle.getString("key2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use extras to send the data.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("SOME_NAME_HERE", theString);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in the target activity you write - in onCreate:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    theString= null;
} else {
    theString = extras.getString("SOME_NAME_HERE");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your dialogbox:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, GeohazardResults.class);
i.putExtra("city", city);
i.putExtra("category", categoty);
startActivity(i);
```

In your new activity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
String city = extras.getString("city");
String category = extras.getString("category");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                .setPositivetiveButton("Geohazard", new 
                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
                            int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class))
                            // intent.putExtra(key,value);
                            intent.putExtra("String1","value1");
                            intent.putExtra("String2","value2");   

                            startActitvity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                )
```

in Acivity

```
           Intent intent = getIntent();
           Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
           if(extras != null){
           //intent.getStringExtra(key)
           string1 = intent.getStringExtra("String1");
           string2 = intent.getStringExtra("String2");
           }
```

i would suggest define keys as constants and use those while passing values, to avoid any confusion

Answer (score 0):

pass intent from your dialog like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, GeohazardResults.class);
        Bundle parameters=new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("city",city);
        parameters.putString("category",category);
        intent.putExtra("key",parameters);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and in the next activity receive thiese values like this.

```
 Intent receivedIntent=getIntent();
        if(receivedIntent!=null){
            Bundle parameters=receivedIntent.getBundleExtra("key");
            if(parameters!=null){
                String city=parameters.getString("city");
                String category=parameters.getString("category");
            }
        }
```